# Alternative implementation of sparse convolution in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, convolution

I have a special convolution kernel: 1) it has a big size (600x600); 2) it is a sparse filter and consists of mostly 0 values and some 1s. I want to apply this kernel to another big image (2000x2000). Since the filter only has 0s and 1s, the convolution operation in this special case is equivalent to the following steps:

1) Compute the coordinates of the 1s relative to the centre point of the convolution filter; 2) Translate the image by each of the relative coordinates; 3) Sum the resulting translations together.

Assume there are in total `n` 1s, then the above will result in `n` translations. We can't have `n` images present in the memory, since the space needed will be `nx2000x2000` and that will result in OOM. I tried using a while loop to save memory space and the code looks like the following:

```
def sum_conv(acc, curr):
    """
    Apply translation to implement convolution. Summation is done in while loop.
    :param acc: (batch, size, size, 1)
    :param curr: (batch, 2)
    :return:
    """
    translation = tf.reshape(curr, [batch_size, 2])
    trans_x = tf.expand_dims(translation[:, 1], axis=-1)
    trans_y = tf.expand_dims(translation[:, 0], axis=-1)
    ones, zeros = tf.ones_like(trans_x), tf.zeros_like(trans_x)
    transform = tf.concat([ones, zeros, trans_x, zeros, ones, trans_y, zeros, zeros], axis=-1)

    # Image: (batch, size, size, 1)
    conv_image = tf.contrib.image.transform(image, transform)
    return acc + conv_image

# Points: (num_points, batch, 2)
# Loop on points (i.e. positions of 1s) to get the results of convolution
i0 = tf.constant(0)
conv_image0 = tf.zeros((batch_size, size, size, 1))
c = lambda i, prev: i < num_points
b = lambda i, prev: (i + 1, sum_conv(prev, tf.gather(points, i, axis=0)))
i, conv_images = tf.while_loop(c, b, (i0, conv_image0))
```

I have two questions.

1) Can anyone help me come up with a simpler implementation of the above algorithm?

2) Is there any operation in TensorFlow that supports sparse convolution?